# Show All Records Due Within 30 Days and also Overdue

Tags: sql

I am setting up a new query to display all records which have a due date within the next 30 days along with all the records which are overdue.

I have used SQL to try and create this rule - but it will only display the records which are due on day 30 - and not the items which are due in between or overdue

```
WHERE DueDate = DateAdd(day, +30, DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, GetDate()), 0))
```

The expected output is a list of items which have a due date within the next 30 days along with all the records which have an overdue due date.

Comment: Which SQL server are you using? Gordon (below) talks about (Microsoft) SQL Server, but there are several others as well - postgresql, mysql, mariadb, orcale, ... The exact syntax and function names vary between them, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need inequalities for things due between tomorrow and 30 days in the future:

```
where DueDate <= DateAdd(day, 30, convert(date, GetDate(), 0)) and
      DueDate > convert(date, getdate())
```

Note that your arcane date arithmetic is just a way to remove the time component.  Converting to `date` is a simpler way to do this -- and supported by all supported versions of SQL Server.

Comment: BTW "unequalities" is the mathematical term for what most programmers call "conditions".

Comment: @rivimey . . . "conditions" includes equality, inequality, `in`, and `not in` (and probably others).  I specifically mean "inequalities".

Comment: I know, and most programmers I know of wouldn't care ... not saying you're wrong though just that this is somebody new to SO and (presumably) to SQL.

Comment: Great - this works and lists all the records with a due date within the next 30 days - However is there also a way to show those with an overdue date?

Comment: @rodm92 . . . You don't mention any column called "overdue date" in your question.  Perhaps you simply want:  `where duedate > convert(date, getdate())`.